# Two blue arrows on desktop icon of installed assembly

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, installation, arrows

I just noticed two opposite facing blue arrows in the upper right corner of the desktop icon of an installed assembly from my Visual Studio 2015 VB.NET Windows form project.  Forums outside of SE seem to suggest these arrows refer to file compression, anti-virus, and possibly a bug.

Since I have re-installed this assembly dozens of times before without noticing these arrows, I am guessing it is the result of a Windows update(?)

It's basically annoying and could cause users to ask for a description, causing extra work.  Is there a way to kill it?

Comment: no, i am using a browser now and don't see any blue arrows.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1001970/two-blue-arrows-at-top-right-of-icons

Comment: @Plutonix, thanks for the link, but what's a VS developer to do to prevent the blue arrows from appearing in users' desktop icon?  You can't tell users they have to go to the installed folder, right click, then advanced.... this would create chaos and a potential disaster.

Comment: Unless your program or your installer enabled the disk compression there's nothing you should be expected to do, you can't really explain why the end-user chose to enable disk compression, **to** that user, he or she needs to know that him/herself, don't you agree?

Comment: You are assuming that the user has never seen those arrows and doesnt know what it means,  If they have compression enabled, they have seen them.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments, and I checked if right-click--> Advanced-->"Compress contents to save disk space" was checked in the C:\Program Files folder and sub-folder, and it's not.  C-drive also has compression turned off.   Will just need to let it go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the InstallAllUsers property of the Setup and Deployment project is set to TRUE, then the two blue arrows will appear on the installed desktop icon, program menu icon, and folders where the assembly is installed.  However, when this property is set to FALSE, it will prevent the arrows from appearing throughout the Windows OS.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing and please mark it as answer, that will help other community members easier search this useful information, this just a reminder :)

Comment: Anyone have a way to remove the arrows with out changing InstallAllUsers property?